# Local variable is updating a class instance variable and not allowing further updates in javascript

Tags: javascript

When I log the current board status after making moves in `playGame`, the board does not update correctly.  Specifically, `tempBoard` in `makeMove` makes changes to the `game.state` board. I thought the `tempBoard` would just be a local variable and would only change the actual board when `updateBoard` is called.  I know it must be something simple I'm missing but can't seem to figure out.  Thanks!

*Console Output below*:

"Original: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"

"Old board: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"

"tempBoard Before: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"

"tempBoard After: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,X"

"From makeMove: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,X"

"Old board: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,X"

"tempBoard Before: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,X"

"tempBoard After: 1,2,X,4,5,6,7,8,X"

"From makeMove: 1,2,X,4,5,6,7,8,X"

"Old board: 1,2,X,4,5,6,7,8,X"

"tempBoard Before: 1,2,X,4,5,6,7,8,X"

"tempBoard After: 1,2,X,4,X,6,7,8,X"

"From makeMove: 1,2,X,4,X,6,7,8,X"

"After moves: 1,2,X,4,X,6,7,8,X"

"OldBoard: 1,2,X,4,X,6,7,8,X"

"Board reset: 1,2,X,4,X,6,7,8,X"

Code Below:

// Game class

```
var Game = function(board,playerToken,compToken){
    this.board = board;
    this.playerToken = playerToken;
    this.compToken = compToken;

    this.state = new State(board);
    this.playerTurn = true;
};

Game.prototype.getPlayerToken = function(){
    return this.playerToken;
};

Game.prototype.getCompToken = function(){
    return this.compToken;
};

Game.prototype.makeMove = function(move,player){
    var moved = false,
        tempBoard = this.state.getBoard();

    if(this.state.getFreeSpots().indexOf(move) >= 0){
        tempBoard[move - 1] = player.getToken();
        moved = true;
    }
    this.state.updateBoard([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);
    console.log("From makeMove: " + this.state.getBoard());
};
```

// State class

```
var State = function(board){
    this.board = board;
};

State.prototype.updateBoard = function(board){
    this.board = board;
};

State.prototype.getBoard = function(){
    return this.board;
};

State.prototype.getTakenSpots = function(player){
    var avail = this.getFreeSpots(),
        taken = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        curBoard = this.board;

    // Filters out taken positions from 'taken' array
    return taken.filter(function(val){
        return avail.indexOf(val) < 0; 
    }).filter(function(val){
        return curBoard[val - 1] === player;
    });
};

State.prototype.getFreeSpots = function(){
    var movesArr = [];

    movesArr = this.board.filter(function(x){
        return typeof x === "number";
    });
    return movesArr;
};
```

// Player class

```
var Player = function(token){
    this.token = token;
};

Player.prototype.getToken = function(){
    return this.token;
};
```

// Play game

```
function playGame(){
    var board = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        game,
        player,
        comp,
        reset = false,
        oldBoard;

    var temp = 0,
        temp2;

    player = new Player('X');
    comp = new Player('O');

    game = new Game(board, player.getToken(),comp.getToken());

    console.log("Original: " + game.state.getBoard());
    oldBoard = game.state.getBoard();
    console.log("Old board: " + oldBoard);

    game.makeMove(9,player);
    console.log("Old board: " + oldBoard);
    game.makeMove(3,player);
    console.log("Old board: " + oldBoard);
    game.makeMove(5,player);
    console.log("After moves: " + game.state.getBoard());
    console.log("OldBoard: " + oldBoard);
    //game.state.updateBoard(oldBoard);
    console.log("Board reset: " + game.state.getBoard());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are objects. Variables (and properties) do not store objects, they store *references* to objects. (Think of it like a number that tells the JavaScript engine where the object is.) So `State#getBoard` returns a reference to its actual `board` array, the one passed into `Game`, not a copy of it. Consider:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(a[0]); // 1
var b = a;         // Reference to the same array, not a copy of it
b[0] = 42;
console.log(a[0]); // 42
```

Passing an object into or out of a function is like doing `b = a` above: The *reference* is the value that gets passed into and out of the function. So:

```js
function foo(array) {
  array[0] = 42;
}
var a = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(a[0]); // 1
foo(a);         // Reference to the same array, not a copy of it
console.log(a[0]); // 42
```

If you want to perform operations on a local copy of the board rather than the real board, you have to copy the array. In ES5 the simple way to do that is `slice` with no arguments:

```
var b = a.slice();
```

`slice` returns a *new* array with a copy of the elements (a shallow copy). Changes to the new array's state have no effect on `a` because they don't refer to the same array.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(a[0]); // 1
var b = a.slice(); // Shallow copy
b[0] = 42;
console.log(a[0]); // 1
console.log(b[0]); // 42
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! I knew I was missing something fundamental with the way I was assigning/retrieving the values.

Answer (score 0):

tempBoard = this.state.getBoard();

This statement gets the actual board . tempBoard contains the reference to the actual board.
If you make any changes actual board would be updated.

Rather do

```
tempBoard = this.state.getBoard().slice()
```